# Unrecognized jQuery function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using a jQuery plugin called coin-slider. I've followed all of the directions in the documentation regarding its installation and usage. When I look at the Firebug console, it tells me that the `coinslider()` function is undefined.

A link to the site is located [here](http://engineercreativity.com/samples/obsession). The site is in a different language, so try to look past that :)

Comment: My firebug showed "Unexpected value align parsing preserveAspectRatio attribute" as the error instead of that it was undefined? I have FF 6, Firebug 1.8.2. The preserveAspectRatio is within the iframe of the video. Not sure if removing that iframe will help or not?

Comment: @Benno: I'll try removing the iframe

Comment: @Benno: iFrame removed, error persists :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You include jQuery twice (some code removed for brevity):

```
<!-- load jQuery and sripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://engineercreativity.com/samples/obsession/wp-content/themes/EngineerCreativity/js/coin-slider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://engineercreativity.com/samples/obsession/wp-content/themes/EngineerCreativity/css/coin-slider-styles.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
/* SLIDEShOW */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#coin-slider').coinslider();
});
</script>

<!-- later: -->

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js?ver=3.2.1'></script>
```

Not only is this last URL suspicious (which version did you want, again?!) but this final include overwrites the original jQuery instance (the one with `coinslider` added!).

**Just include jQuery once, and make sure that you do it *before* you include the coinslider plugin.**